# Plan self motion in Moveit

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to plan two subsequent motions with Moveit. The first motion is a relatively unconstrained motion to an end effector pose. I would like the second motion to move the first roll joint to a specified position while maintaining the end effector pose. (self motion.)

I can plan the first motion just fine. I am trying to acheive the self motion by adding a goal constraint to the original motion plan request, and adding a path constraint that fixes the end effector pose.

Relevant code:

`//First motion:
     moveit_msgs::Constraints pose_goal = kinematic_constraints::constructGoalConstraints("link_t", pose, tolerance_pose, tolerance_angle);  
      mp_request.goal_constraints.push_back(pose_goal);
      mp_request.allowed_planning_time = 10.0;
      
      moveit_msgs::GetMotionPlan mp_srv;
      mp_srv.request.motion_plan_request = mp_request;
      mp_srv.response.motion_plan_response = mp_response;
      if(!mp_client.call(mp_srv)){
        std::cout setStateValues(mp_response.trajectory.joint_trajectory.points.back().positions);
      joint_state_msg.name = joint_state_group->getJointModelGroup()->getJointModelNames();
      joint_state_msg.position = mp_response.trajectory.joint_trajectory.points.back().positions;
      joint_state_publisher.publish(joint_state_msg);
      
      ros::spinOnce();
      
      current_joints_ = joint_state_msg;
      mp_request.start_state.joint_state = current_joints_;
  ////////Self motion/////////////////////////
  moveit_msgs::Constraints path_eef_constraints_, joint_constraints_;
  moveit_msgs::JointConstraint goal_joint_constraint_;
  moveit_msgs::OrientationConstraint eef_orientation_constraint_;
  moveit_msgs::PositionConstraint eef_pos_constraint_;
  
  //Set Joint_1 goal constraint and add to goal_constraints.
  goal_joint_constraint_.joint_name = joint_state_msg.name.at(0);
  goal_joint_constraint_.position = current_joints_.position.at(0)-1.57;
  goal_joint_constraint_.position = 0;
  goal_joint_constraint_.tolerance_above = .1;
  goal_joint_constraint_.tolerance_below = .1;
  goal_joint_constraint_.weight = .5;
  
  //add joint goal constraint:    
  mp_request.goal_constraints.back().joint_constraints.push_back(goal_joint_constraint_);
  
  //Set path constraint:
  mp_request.path_constraints = pose_goal;
  mp_srv.request.motion_plan_request = mp_request;`

The first motion goes off without a hitch, and If I do the second motion with the joint specified, but no path constraint, it plans correctly as well. However, when I add the path constraint, I get the following errors:

```
[ERROR] [1368026713.167017264]: Poses vector must have size: 1
[ERROR] [1368026713.167240823]: Poses vector must have size: 1
[ INFO] [1368026713.168012375]: No planner specified. Using default.
[ WARN] [1368026713.168312286]: Skipping invalid start state (invalid bounds)
[ERROR] [1368026713.168460131]: Motion planning start tree could not be initialized!
[ INFO] [1368026713.168488571]: No solution found after 0.000251 seconds
[ WARN] [1368026713.177067471]: Goal sampling thread never did any work.
[ INFO] [1368026713.177400962]: Unable to solve the planning problem"
Motion planning failure: error_code: 1
```

I would guess that the Poses vector error is what is killing me, but I'm not sure what's triggering this error. Can anyone provide any insight?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62396/plan-self-motion-in-moveit/) by [flyingRobot78](https://answers.ros.org/users/2665/flyingrobot78/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-05-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey flyingRobot78,

Could you please ask future MoveIt! related questions on the moveit-users mailing list: moveit-users@googlegroups.com. Its easier for us to track MoveIt! specific questions there.

Regarding your question:

(1) Could you please mention which robot you are doing this with - you mention first roll joint but without knowing the robot its hard to put this in context.

(2) If you are trying to move only one joint of a robot, the right way to do this (if you want to do it with planning) is to have a group just consisting of that one joint and move it directly. The way you are doing it seems overly complicated for a 1 DOF motion.

(3) when you specify path constraints, you need to specify a "planning volume" by setting the workspace bounds in the motion plan request: workspace_parameters.min_corner and workspace_parameters.max_corner.

---

Originally posted by [Sachin Chitta](https://answers.ros.org/users/39/sachin-chitta/) with karma: 1304 on 2013-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0